# How do I convert year to seconds?

Tags: javascript

I will prompt the user to enter the years he lived then it should return the seconds he lived.

The code:

```
let use = prompt("Enter number of years u lived: ");
let u = parseInt(use)
let time = new Date() 
let compute = time.getFullYear() - u



console.log(compute.getSeconds()+time.getFullYear());
```

But I get an error that says 'Uncaught TypeError: compute.getSeconds is not a function'

Comment: That getFullYear doesn't return a "year" (as in "date"), but just an integer (2022)

Comment: To get the number of seconds someone has lived, you would need more than their age in years, you'd need their date of birth (otherwise you are rounding to the closest year, which is a lot of seconds off)

Comment: @DBS - hour, minute and the very second they were considered "alive" :) difficult information to get

Comment: @vsync Indeed, but most people will know their birthday, so that seems like a level of detail that you can reasonably ask for.

Comment: Also your logic is wrong. You're asking users to enter number of years they lived (let's say 30), then you get current time (year 2022), then you substract, so you get 1992. From this result you wont get the time they lived.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming an approximation is fine (because you're not asking for a birth date anyway), it might be the easiest to just multiply the number by the number of seconds per year.

```
const seconds = years * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
```

This is not exact because it's not accounting for leap day and leap second rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it the naive way:- multiply the year by '31,536,000'. But this will lack accuracy.

Comment: it doesnt matter because they wont input exact time they were born. But I guess OP is trying to learn Dates?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, if the purpose is to learn the 'DateJS' library, then my approach isn't that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `compute` an integer value by using `getFullYear()`. That's why you're getting a `TypeError`.

To calculate the number of seconds lived you can do what Evert suggests [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72844547/12233224).